# Close Word UserForm

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have VBA that is looping from some directory, opens Word files, copies some text, puts the copied text into Excel, and then closes Word. The code works but I have some files that inside have some UserForms. When that type of document starts a pop up UserForm opens. Until I close that form the code is waiting for closure. So I am trying (without success) to close that pop up UserForm. My code:

```
Sub copy_from_word_to_excel(ByVal aFilename As String)

   Dim objWord As Object
   Dim objDoc As Object
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim objLoop As Object


   Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(aFilename, ReadOnly:=False)

    objWord.Visible = False




    For Each objLoop In objDoc.VBA.UserForms
        If TypeOf objLoop Is UserForm Then Unload objLoop
    Next objLoop

    objDoc.ReadOnlyRecommended = False
    objDoc.RemovePersonalInformation = True

    j = j + 1
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 1).Value = aFilename
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(j, 1), Address:=aFilename, TextToDisplay:=aFilename
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 2).Value = objDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 3).Value = objDoc.Paragraphs(2).Range.Text
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 4).Value = objDoc.Paragraphs(32).Range.Text
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 5).Value = objDoc.Paragraphs(33).Range.Text
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 6).Value = objDoc.Paragraphs(34).Range.Text


      objDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
      Set objDoc = Nothing

      objWord.Quit
      Set objWord = Nothing

End Sub
```

I am trying to close the Word UserForm from Excel with this piece of code (but it is not good):

```
For Each objLoop In objDoc.VBA.UserForms
    If TypeOf objLoop Is UserForm Then Unload objLoop
Next objLoop
```

What can be done?